# Is it possible to set the screen resolution from inside the GRUB terminal?

Tags: grub2

When inside the GRUB2 screen, if you hit C you are taken to console mode.

Is it possible from that console to set the screen resolution.

Note: I know it can be changed in the grub config. I want to know if there is a command you can type in to change the screen resolution from inside that console.

Answer (score 12):

Changing **`gfxmode`** variable and temporary **switching to different [terminal_output](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/terminal_005foutput.html)** (console or vga_text) should change screen resolution.

```
terminal_output console
set gfxmode=1280x1024
terminal_output gfxterm
```

`videoinfo` command shows available resolutions

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation of GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#gfxmode) suggests that the `gfxmode` is treated specially: setting it will set the screen resolution.

So, the syntax would be:

```
set gfxmode=WIDTHxHEIGHT
```

or

```
set gfxmode=WIDTHxHEIGHTxDEPTH
```

You can use the `videoinfo` command to list the resolutions supported by your hardware+firmware combination. You can also list multiple resolutions separated by either commas or semicolons, and GRUB will pick the first resolution the hardware can support.

If you want the Linux kernel to maintain the resolution that was set by GRUB, you'll also need:

```
set gfxpayload=keep
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work :( But thanks for the help.